# Efficient way to get the first item satisfying a condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using pySpark, I want to get the first element from a column satisfying a condition. I want this operation to be efficient so that the first time the condition is satisfied the element is returned.

Currently, I am trying

```
df.filter(df.seller_id==6).take(1)
```

It is taking a lot of time and I think something is causing a scan through the entire data or the read of the entire data. However, I think the filter should be pushed down while reading the data and the first moment the seller_id is 6 it should return that value. The first row in df_sales has seller_id as 6 so I think reading that row should be enough.

How can I manage something more efficient than the code I have mentioned?

Comment: Did you check `df.filter(df.seller_id==6).explain("formatted")`?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I only now saw what I was missing. I had not specified a schema and the column seller_id is being read as a string hence the filter was not pushed. Now that I specify schema with seller_id as integertype then the filter is getting pushed. I must say that if spark if intelligent enough to cast seller_id to integertype automatically later on then maybe it should push the cast operation along with the filter. I am not sure though

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("seller_id")\
.orderBy("how you determine first in partition")

df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec)).where(col("row_number") == 1)
```

I think the above code should do what you are looking for, it partitions your data by the seller ID and then within that partition you will need to order on a column in the `orderBy()` function, this orderBy will rank your rows based on this ordering and then in the last where we take the first row from that ordered partition